# How to get simple date (“Month Number”)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im trying to get the date, but im wanting to to return ex `”Oct 29”`. Ive tryed using split, but it changes everyday. Heres what I have so far.

```
Let date = Date().split(“ 2021”)[0];
```

This returns `day<string> month day<int>`

Comment: see: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: That dosnt exsist
It just give an error 
`Date().getMonth() is not a function`

Comment: it is a method [Date.prototype.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) but you have to call `new Date()` not `Date()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) function to achieve what you want. This code below will generate the output you wanted (`"Oct 29"`).

```
let date = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format it there are various inbuilt methods or do this:

```
Let date = Date().toString().substring(4,10);
```